# How to substitute a Maven dependency of a project for its fork on GitHub?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, github

I have a Maven project in Eclipse using a dependency from GitHub and it compiles and runs fine. However, I need to make some changes to the dependency while still retaining access to the rest of its functionality. The obvious solution is to fork it and substitute the new forked project for the old dependency. I got so far as forking it onto my own account, but being new to Maven, I'm unsure what exactly to do next.

There are two references to it in the pom, but what about imports, and maybe some other references that I'm not aware of yet? Plus, the dependency finder can't seem to find the new fork. I'm afraid I might change something in an unintended way, dirtiyng up the project and setting myself up for manually fixing the errors for hours on end.

What's the proper way of removing the old dependency and putting the new one exactly in its place?

Comment: Sorry, I got a bit distracted by all the problems on the project and elsewhere and I forgot about his question. Feedback updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. After you forked the dependency, download a local copy to your workstation.
2. In that copy, you can modify the Maven coordinates (artifact ID or/and the version) of this dependency. Then make your changes.
3. perfom `mvn clean install`. This will put the modified dependency to your local Maven repository (on your machine).
4. In the project's pom.xml that references to the altered dependency, adapt the new coordinates.
5. as @lexicore wrote:

> If you use different groupId/artifactId (that would be cleaner) you
>   may also need to exclude the original dependency from other
>   dependencies. Check mvn dependency:tree for dependencies which you
>   have to add exclusions to.

6. now your own project will use the modified dependency.

Comment: If you want to use your fork for remote builds and have a repository (at  sonatype or centralRepository for example) update your groupId and run 'mvn deploy' to push it to the Maven Repository

Answer (score 1):

> What's the proper way of removing the old dependency and putting the new one exactly in its place?

None.

Same Maven coordinates === same dependency. Period. If you want to modify something (as you do), use different Maven coordinates (`groupId`/`artifactId`/`version`). If you want to change something but still use the old coordinates, you'll get all sorts of problems. How would builds out there know which dependencies they have to use?

The easiest way is probably to just change the version to some higher version and include the forked dependency explicitly. Thus directly included dependency will overwrite other versions in the dependency graph.

If you use different `groupId`/`artifactId` (that would be cleaner) you may also need to exclude the original dependency from other dependencies. Check `mvn dependency:tree` for dependencies which you have to add `exclusions` to.

Also if you just patch some code, change the Maven coordinates, and build your forked dependency, the result should have a correct `pom.xml` so transitive dependencies should work as well. If the original code changes you'll need to rebase you changes on top of that. Not sure if it is viable long-term, you might want to contribute your patch to the original project or request a feature that the part you've customized is customizable OOTB.